# Position Multiple Charts in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm confused as to how positioning of multiple charts work in D3. The end goal is to create a multi-chart dashboard.

Take [this multiple chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480). I don't understand why the second chart (top right) has chosen that position. There's nothing in the code (that I can see) that positions the second chart to the right of the first. How would I go about positioning the second chart below the first?

I'm new to D3 and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVGs are displayed `inline` by default. That's why, in the code you linked, the first SVG gets the top left corner, while the second one is positioned on the right.

Check this demo, both SVGs are appended to the body, the first one on the top left corner and the second one at its right:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("foo")
  .data([1, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to position the SVGs one above the other, use `display: block`.

Here is the same code with that change only. Now the second SVG is appended below the first:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("foo")
  .data([1, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The way it works is CSS. The code created 2 `<svg>` DOM elements in a `<body>`. Here's [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j499uqL2/)

You can utilize this to create your own multiple charts. There are also other techniques possible (to create both of them in a single `<svg>` element and handle translate transformation for `<g>` elements containing individual charts on your own). Here's an example for the latter: [Scatterplot Matrix Brushing](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663)